# Nodejs http request array, getting data despite some errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, axios

I am fetching data about user tastes from an external API by making a series of GET requests. I try to do this in an async fashion using the axios library. The array of promises I am creating should resolve to give me the data, but when the API returns a 404 for any of the requests, the entire array of promises is treated as having been rejected. My understanding is that this is normal.

However, I would like to have a way to receive and process data from the successful requests even while some requests have received a 404 error.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fetchContent = async (req, res) => {
  const favorites = ['food', 'music', 'movies'];

  const user_id = 84;

  const promises = favorites.map(fav => {
    return axios.get(api_url, { params: { user: user_id, category: fav } });
  });

  const results = await axios.all(promises);
  results.map(result => {
    // do something with result
  });
};
```

If the API has no data on a user's preferences in a certain category, the response will be:

```
{"status": 404, "message": "Not Found"}
```

I tried adding a .catch() statement to the end of my .get() requests, but it's clear to me that that solution doesn't work because Node complains about an unhandled promise rejection.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this line of code in a try/catch block. This is the line that is throwing the unhandled promise rejection error.

```
const results = await axios.all(promises);
```